# What is wrong with my equation?

Tags: equations

I'm using overleaf to write my paper.

There is an equation

```
$$\frac{L_{t_2}}{h_{t_1}}=\frac{L_{t_2}}{o_{t_2}}\frac{o_{t_2}}{h_{t_1}}$$
```

It shows normally.

But when I tried to write it as a multiple line equation following overleaf's guide

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}

\frac{L_{t_2}}{h_{t_1}}&=\frac{L_{t_2}}{o_{t_2}}\frac{o_{t_2}}{h_{t_1}}\\
&= ...

\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I got an error. It shows `missing $ inserted`, `misplaced alignment tab character &` and other errors. What have I done wrong?

Comment: you can not have blank lines, note you should not use `$$` in LaTeX either.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why shouldn't I use `$$`? If so, how should I write a line equation?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no error messages after removing blank lines. But I don't use Overleaf.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, amsmath, amsfonts}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            \frac{L_{t_2}}{h_{t_1}}&=\frac{L_{t_2}}{o_{t_2}}\frac{o_{t_2}}{h_{t_1}}\\
            &= ...
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Never thought a blank line would affect the result so much.

Comment: @user900476 If you really want a blank line, you can put a `%` somewhere in the otherwise blank line to have an almost blank line.